# Compare and Equality of string dates in c#

Tags: c#

I have 2 string dates and i want to check both string dates are equal or not. The first date is in yyyy-mm-dd format and the second one is in yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS format.

How to compare and check equality of both dates in C# ?

EDIT : Is it possible to determine which format the dates are in ? Because sometimes not able identify which date is in which format. Dates are coming from diff databases.

Comment: Convert them to proper format (`DateTime`) and compare the value, not the string representation.

Comment: Are they in "DateTime" variables?

Comment: two string variables hold the date values. It is not DateTime variables.

Comment: Are the dates in the database in string format or Date format?

Comment: @StevieB raises a good point. Depending on how you acquire this data, you might be doing multiple back-and-forth conversions.

Comment: Are they equal if the dates match regardless of the time-of-day, or only if the dates match and the time-of-day is midnight?

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach would be:

```
shortDate == longDate.Substring(0,10)
```

A better approach would be to parse them:

```
DateTime
  .ParseExact(shortDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 
DateTime
  .ParseExact(longDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  .Date
```

EDIT:

```
var DateFormats = new string[] { "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" };

DateTime
  .ParseExact(shortDate, DateFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
  .Date == 
DateTime
  .ParseExact(longDate, DateFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
  .Date
```

Comment: Error thrown : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. the long date value is 2012-05-12 13:00:00  and the shortdate value is 2012-05-12 13:00:00

Comment: But in your question you said the short date was format "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstandings. Question edited.

Comment: Answer improved based on edited question

Comment: This overload of `ParseExact` tries the different date formats and if one is found to work, uses it.